# mvn install error: package does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have this scenarion:

1. I have a maven project with spring boot where  i just have some tipical pojo classes inside this package structure like: com.demo.core

**pom structure**

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

***com/demo/core/Person.java***

2. Then im trying to use that base project as a dependency of other spring boot project which is responsible of database persistence.

   - here i use spring data, lombok and others.

***Second project pom dependencies:***

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  local dependencies -->
**
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-baseproject</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> 
**
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

3. I run mvn clean install in base project and verify that the jar file is in my local .m2 repository structure.
4. when i try to run `mvn clean install` in the second project i got an error saying that the package com.demo.core does not exits therefore did not find classes inside that package.

Error details:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< com.demo:jpa-dataprovider-simple >---------------
[INFO] Building jpa-dataprovider-simple 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ jpa-dataprovider-simple ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ jpa-dataprovider-simple ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple-pos/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[4,35] package com.demo.core.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[8,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TerminalConfig
  location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.mapper.TerminalConfigJpaMapper
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[18,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TerminalConfig
  location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.mapper.TerminalConfigJpaMapper
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[9,35] package com.demo.core.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[10,36] package com.demo.core.gateway does not exist
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[14,54] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class TerminalConfigGateway
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[24,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TerminalConfig
  location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.gateway.JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TerminalConfig
  location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.gateway.JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.714 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-14T18:08:20-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project jpa-dataprovider-simple: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/d/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[4,35] package com.demo.core.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[8,59] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TerminalConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.mapper.TerminalConfigJpaMapper
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[18,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TerminalConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.mapper.TerminalConfigJpaMapper
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[9,35] package com.demo.core.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[10,36] package com.demo.core.gateway does not exist
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[14,54] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class TerminalConfigGateway
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[24,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TerminalConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.gateway.JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl
[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple/jpa-dataprovider-simple/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/gateway/JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TerminalConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.demo.jpa.dataprovider.gateway.JpaTerminalConfigGatewayImpl
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Have any one a clue how to solve this???

Im using:

Spring Tool Suite 4 
Version: 4.5.0.RELEASE

java-8-openjdk-amd64

maven 3.6.0

springboot version 2.1.11
Thanks in advance.

There is something new to me, when i review inside jar file the structure is like this:

[Jar structure generated by spring boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wicnI.png)

**For some reason i changed the maven config in eclipse to use the installed and not the embedbeb one, but now i get this error.**

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.619 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.oxypora.jpa.dataprovider.JpaDataproviderSimplePosApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.oxypora.jpa.dataprovider.JpaDataproviderSimplePosApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.015 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.oxypora.jpa.dataprovider.JpaDataproviderSimplePosApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/oxypora/pos/core/gateway/TerminalConfigGateway.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/oxypora/pos/core/gateway/TerminalConfigGateway.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Where should be this package? Where should be following classes: TerminalConfig; TerminalConfigGateway?

Comment: They are in the first project which i call core project and are used in the second one which i called jpa-dataprovider

Class -> TerminalConfig   -> package com.demo.core.entity 
Interface -> TerminalConfigGateway -> package com.demo.core.gateway

Comment: Please esure that the files are in the dependency jar. Are they generated in the core project?

Comment: yes i verified the jar file and the classes are there

Comment: looks like the source files are not copied in their entirety. The very first error gives a clue that "com.demo.core.entity" package is missing which is typically hosted in com/demo/core/entity directory.```[ERROR] /home/demo/sts-eclipse-wrkspace-simple-pos/jpa-dataprovider-simple-pos/src/main/java/com/demo/jpa/dataprovider/mapper/TerminalConfigJpaMapper.java:[4,35] package com.demo.core.entity does not exist```

Comment: For some reason i changed the maven config in eclipse to use the installed and not the embedbeb one, but now i get this error

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution when you have two or more springboot projects and you want to wire them one as dependency of others.

The solution is not to use spring-boot-maven-plugin, this plugin override the normal package of the jar causing your classes and package structure to move under BOOT-INF/classes.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, springboot project generated a diferent jar structure configured in the metainf file, so that classes are not pleced in the tipical folders.

what i did was to change the core project to a simple maven project with out spring boot complexity, and now the second project (springboot one) compiled without problems.

There was not nescessary to have the base project as a springboot one.